# Changing UV seams, no change in Cycles?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm new, and I'm texturing my first model following the very popular series on YouTube by BlenderGuru. The texture looks really nice, the only issue is that there's ugly seams where I don't want them, and as far as I know, that's from UV unwrapping. I have gone back and changed where seams were, and it's represented on the UV/Image editor, but when I go into cycles to look at it with the texture, the seam is still there. Am I misunderstanding how this all works?

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSr25.jpg)

[image]

The circled part is where there are no seams in the UV, but then in cycles it shows the seam. There WAS a seam there before I removed it.

[image]

Comment: I select all and then hit U, > Unwrap. In the UV Image editor I see the new "setup" of the unwrap. But when I go into cycles, I still see ugly seams where I had them to begin with. Is there an "update UV" button somewhere?

Comment: I updated the main post with pictures of my problem.

Comment: Could you add a screen shot of your material node set up into your question as well? Here's a couple of things to try: In Object Mode select the anvil and press CTRL+"A" and select "Scale". Then Un Wrap again. In the UV editor select your texture image as the background for the UV Map.

Comment: Added a picture of the nodes. The scale thing didn't work unfortunately and I don't know how to set a background image in the UV editor.

Comment: It looks like you maybe missing a seam(s) in the area you drew a circle around. Maybe revisit His tutorial around 16:30 where he explains that part of the anvil.

Comment: The point is that any change to the seams does nothing... I even cleared all seams and went to cycles and it is all messed up. I figured it out though, I think I would need to redo the seams on the original mesh and then rebake the normals. 

Removing that bottom node, which is loading the normal map I made, fixes the ugly seams because I think it is now using the correct UV map. I have a vague idea but still confused.

Comment: There isn't any reason to mark seams and unwrap highpoly model, only lowpoly requires that. Normal map can be one of multiple reasons for that seam; seam from image texture can be as well (not necessarily, it's all theoretically). UV map updates after unwrapping (pressing U) unless uv map is pinned (which isn't from your screenshot). Though island on the bottom right in UV map seems off to me with quite a bit of stretching, maybe check it with image in the viewport and add more seams

Comment: It may help if you uploaded you .blend using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and pasting the resulting link into your original question. Also, the Seams you mark on your mesh are telling Blender where to "Unfold" your mesh into the UV Map not where to "Split" it.

Comment: I'm definitely still wrapping my head around UV unwrapping. I've solved my issue as stated above, but somehow along the way I messed up the normal map? It's completely off center now. I had dents along the edge of the anvil and now they're on top of it.

Comment: Ok when I tried the "scale" option above, I think it caused the normals to be offset because i hadn't done that "Scale" thing before, so i just had to redo the baking of normals. Now everything is working nicely and I know to scale things.